# How to exclude sub @Imports in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

Here is what I have:

```java
@Configuration
@Import({ClassA.class})
public class SomeClass
```

```java
@Configuration
@Import({ClassB.class, ClassC.class})
public class ClassA
```

In my application, I want to `@Import({SomeClass.class})`, but do not want `ClassC`

How do I achieve that?